# Error in solr for "date" data index

Tags: solr

I'm getting following error in log file while indexing data to solr.This error appears when i'm indexing "Date" info to solr. I'm using Oracle 10G and solr version 3.5. I think date format may be wrong here. I checked enough couldn't find the solution. Following is my error:

```
date format "'date1'='2012-05-23T09:47:23'"
------
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=12603] Error adding field     'date1'='2012-05-23T09:47:23'
at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:324)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:60)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:115)
at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:158)
at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:79)
at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1398)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:212)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:634)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Date String:'2012-05-23T09:47:23'
at org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.parseMath(DateField.java:165)
at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.createField(TrieField.java:421)
at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDateField.createField(TrieDateField.java:120)
at org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField.createField(SchemaField.java:104)
at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:203)
at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:281)
```

Is there a mistake from my side.Plz help me...I`m new to solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the trailing Z - i e UTC timezone which is mandatory. It should look something like this:

```
2012-05-23T09:47:23Z
```

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html

Comment: :Thanks for replying.But i`m using Oracle 10G.I tried appending "000Z".It didn`t work.Anyway i`ll try this and let you know.

Comment: :It didn`t work,I tried with "SELECT UPPER(cus_att), GETXSDDATE(" + ColumnName + ")+'Z' FROM tab_name" in oracle.I`ll fetch then add the data into solr.But fetching itself failing.

Comment: You might specify the datetimeformat for the date field in Solr instead of trying to change the output of Oracle: <field column="date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" locale="en" />

Comment: :You mean to say in Schema xml I have to include this code ahh?

Comment: Right. <field column="CAD1" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" locale="en" />

Comment: :I have included the code "<field name="DATE1" type="date" indexed="true" datetimeformat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" stored="true" />".And the query is like "Select col_name1,date_col from tab_name" in oracle.But it`s still failing.Where am I going wrong here??

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This goes into data-config.xml not schema.xml. This is a simple example:     <entity name="id" 
            query="select id,date from mytable" 
            transformer="DateFormatTransformer">
       <field column="id" name="solr_id"/>
       <field column="date" name="solr_date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"/>
    </entity>

Comment: :Okay i`ll check and reply.Thanks

Comment: :I dont find the file you specified.Do I need to include the file?Or any other alternative way is better I guess.

Comment: Have you put the DIH entity- and field-definitions in a separate file? The file data-config.xml may have another name, check the name of the file dataimporthandler in solrconfig. Or have you put the config directly in solrconfig.xml? Although a bit dated, there is good overview how to setup the configuration at this place: http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2009/10/solr-%E2%80%93-features-and-configuration-details/

Comment: :Thanks for setup link...I`ll go through.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    convertTimestamp {
      field :To
      inputFormats : ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
      inputTimezone : UTC
      outputFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"                                 
      outputTimezone : Europe/London
    }
  }
```

If you're using this piece of morphlines code from the kite-examples-morphlines package, if you  look on the out outputformat column they have made an error. it should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'". hope this helps anyone else using morphlines.